# Functional equation $m(x^y)=m(x)+m(y)$.

Tags: functional-equations

> Find all functions $m : \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}^+$ such that$$m(x^y)=m(x)+m(y)$$

Comment: Do you have any ideas?  What happens if $y=1$?  Or if $x=1$?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea. This is my first encounter with functional equations.

Answer (score 5):

Set $x=1$ and conclude what the function should be.

Comment: If x=1, I will get this function m(1)=m(1)+m(y), which implies m(y)=0?

Comment: @Max Yes ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: So, this implies m(x)=0=m(y) for any y,x in R+. So, the only solution is m(x)=0?

Comment: @Max Yes ${}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Since the function is true for all positive real values, it should obviously be true for $x=1$.

Substituting $x=1$, we get:

$m(1) = m(1) + m(y) \implies m(y) = 0$

So the function equation becomes : $m(x^y) = m(x)$

You can easily find the function value from here.

Hope the answer is clear !